# Way to take screenshot of view faster

Tags: android

In my app I show all errors by taking a screenshot, grayscaling it, and adding error text on it. This is how I take screenshot:

```
private Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View v) {
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getWidth(), v.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    v.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}

final ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) getWindow().getDecorView();
Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromView(root);
```

And then convert bitmap to grayscale, add a text and show. 
My problem is that `getBitmapFromView` on some devices (`Galaxy S5` unexpected btw) takes 500-700 ms to complete. My question is if there is any faster way to take screenshot of the view, or of entire screen? I have tried `View.getDrawingCache()`, and it's the same slow. If I'm right, then it works the same way as my `getBitmapFromView` method.

**EDIT:**

Ok, I figured out what caused so slow performance using Android Monitor and method profiling in my case. It was the `GradientDrawable` taking 80% of time to draw. I have optimized it, and it now takes about 150 ms. to take screenshot. But the question stays the same: Is there any faster way to do it? Maybe using NDK?

Comment: have you tried using Bitmap.Config.RGB_565 in stead of Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888 or do you need to use the alpha channel?

Comment: @Neil, yes, I've tried all, `RGB_565`, `ARGB_8888`, `ARGB_4444`. All work the same slow. The only one that works faster is `ALPHA_8`, but it makes no sense for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your custome view here

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    this.buildDrawingCache();
}
```

To get your CacheBitmap just

```
view.getDrawingCache();
```

This works for me ,i can get the CacheBitmap immediately

But it's a bad ideal that may cause some performance problems

Comment: thanks, but the problem is that I don't use my custom view. As said, I use `getWindow().getDecorView();`